# Modificar tabela PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela de faturamento mensal que exibe os ganhos de janeiro a dezembro. Ela soma todos os valores da tabela `pagseguro` (coluna `ProdValor_1`).

Abaixo está o código da tabela:

```
<?php    

$mes = array("0", "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");

for($i = 1; $i < count($mes); $i++) {

    $sql = "select sum(ProdValor_1) as total from pagseguro where DtCad between '".$ano."-".$i."-01 00:00:00' and '".$ano."-".$i."-31 23:59:59' and TipoVenda='cl' and situacao='3'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $clconf = $result['total'];

    $sql = "select sum(ProdValor_1) as total from pagseguro where DtCad between '".$ano."-".$i."-01 00:00:00' and '".$ano."-".$i."-31 23:59:59' and TipoVenda='cl' and situacao='1'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $clnconf = $result['total'];

    $sql = "select sum(ProdValor_1) as total from pagseguro where DtCad between '".$ano."-".$i."-01 00:00:00' and '".$ano."-".$i."-31 23:59:59' and TipoVenda='cl' and situacao='2'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $clcanc = $result['total'];

    $sql = "select sum(ProdValor_1) as total from pagseguro where DtCad between '".$ano."-".$i."-01 00:00:00' and '".$ano."-".$i."-31 23:59:59' and TipoVenda='pl' and situacao='3'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $cpconf = $result['total'];

    $sql = "select sum(ProdValor_1) as total from pagseguro where DtCad between '".$ano."-".$i."-01 00:00:00' and '".$ano."-".$i."-31 23:59:59' and TipoVenda='pl' and situacao='1'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $cpnconf = $result['total'];

    $sql = "select sum(ProdValor_1) as total from pagseguro where DtCad between '".$ano."-".$i."-01 00:00:00' and '".$ano."-".$i."-31 23:59:59' and TipoVenda='pl' and situacao='2'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $cpcanc = $result['total'];

    echo "
    <tr>
        <td align='center' style='background-color:#FCFBC5'><strong><center>$mes[$i]</center></strong></td>
        <td align='center' style='color:#36B851'><strong>".moeda($clconf)."</strong></td>
        <td align='center' style='color:#B17A7B'><strong>".moeda($clnconf)."</strong></td>
        <td align='center' style='color:#B17A7B; border-right:2px solid #B3B3B3'><strong>".moeda($clcanc)."</strong></td>
        <td align='center' style='color:#36B851'><strong>".moeda($cpconf)."</strong></td>
        <td align='center' style='color:#B17A7B'><strong>".moeda($cpnconf)."</strong></td>
        <td align='center' style='color:#B17A7B'><strong>".moeda($cpcanc)."</strong></td>
    </tr>
    ";
}

?>
```

Existe uma outra coluna na tabela `pagseguro` que é registrada as taxas de cada pagamento. Eu preciso modificar ela para exibir os resultados descontando essas taxas.

Por exemplo para janeiro teve um total de 500,00 reais em vendas e, nesse mesmo período, desses 500,00 reais 50,00 reais é de taxa/desconto. Então ele deve exibir os 450,00 reais.

Comment: Tem como colocar a estrutura da tabela na pergunta? O resultado deve ser `sum(ProdValor_1) - sum(taxas)`? Já tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Coloquei a estrutura ali.. Não tentei isso, vou tentar

Comment: Era exatamente isso, valew :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve seu problema

```
SELECT ( SUM(ProdValor_1) - SUM(taxas_ps) ) AS total FROM pagseguro
```

Esse código é apenas para exemplificar, você precisa apenas fazer essa pequena alteração na sua consulta SQL. Realizando a subtração entre  soma dos valores da coluna **ProdValor_1** e a coluna **taxas_ps**.

O resto da sua consulta continua como está.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, achei que não seria tão simples assim. rsrs

Muito obrigado ;)